# How to link Qt API & GStreamer on Qt-Creator (MacOs)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, gstreamer

I am on El Capitan 10.11.4 and I want to install Qt5 to create and develop project on Qt-Creator. I downloaded the installator on [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). And I checked like that :
[check list installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X656c.png)

Now I opened a project in Qt-Creator :

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>
```

During the running of qmake, it can't find 'gst', it can't also find 'QObject' or something else from Qt.

To solve problem from 'gst', I have tried to includ library path to GStreamer Framework or to pass by 'PKG-CONFIG' like that :

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/
INCLUDEPATH += -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include
LIBS += -L/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Libraries/
LIBS += -framework GStreamer
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/
PKG_CONFIG_PATH += /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Libraries/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/pkgconfig
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0
```

But nothing works ! 
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Can you add your compiler error log?

Comment: `Exécution des étapes pour le projet Gst-multiscreens-client...

Débute : "/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin/qmake" /Users/P0ppoff/Documents/4RICM/8S/Projet/SmartProjector/Gst-multiscreens-client/Gst-multiscreens-client.pro -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug

Project ERROR: gstreamer-1.0 development package not found

Le processus "/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin/qmake" s'est terminé avec le code 3.

Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet Gst-multiscreens-client (kit : Desktop Qt 5.6.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"`

Comment: And you definitely have the `gstreamer-1.0-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes, I checked I had it. I reinstalled [gstreamer-1.0-dev](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.8.0/) to confirm installation. I tried to link framework with QtCreator :

`mac: LIBS += -F/Library/Frameworks/ -framework GStreamer
INCLUDEPATH += 

/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers
DEPENDPATH += 

/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers`

But now it says : *framework to found GStreamer* and *linker command failed with exit code 1*

Comment: what happens when you execute `pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0` hope that can be done on OSX (On Linux this works)?

Comment: It works in terminal : **pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0**
`-D_REENTRANT -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/include/glib-2.0 -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/glib-2.0/include -L/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`

But I have to export PKG_CONFIG_PATH in _.bashrc_. How to make this export in QT-Creator ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by changing the path of the GStreamer.framework to:

```
your_qt_folder / version / clang_64 / lib
```

and just adding this to the .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/THE_NEW_PATH/GStreamer.framework/Headers/"
LIBS += -framework GStreamer
```